# How does a tiger growl make you feel?

Tags: animals

How does a tiger growl make you feel?

Comment: Sabertooth tiger or any type

Comment: While this may have been on topic 9 years ago, it is not in scope for Sound Design.

Answer (score 1):

It of course depends entirely on the context - if it is about to eat me & I am defenceless then I will be feeling fear/panic etc (or maybe elation/peace if I have accepted my inevitable end)  but if its a cute furry cub and I am completely safe I will not be feeling fear...

Comment: @tim Check out the big cat sounds if you haven't already.  Some remarkably freaky/human sounding stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Hello kitty.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NonmwOcnQKQ&feature=related

Answer (score 0):

Big cat sounds.  Some really cool stuff in here.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHZm52nvBB4&feature=related

Answer (score 0):

Last summer I took my three year old son to a zoo. We saw a tiger that was walking restlessly in an outdoor cage. It came towards us and a inch thick glass was all that seperated us fron the tiger who stood 3 meters away. The tiger let a few roars out. It was honestly quite humbling and startling. It had a very low roar. Wish I would have had my H4n with me.

Answer (score 0):

Grrrrrrrrrreat!

[youtube]3b-utGn-UUI[/youtube]

Comment: Wow, that's a throwback. I used to love windsurfing with the tiger

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard a Tiger growl.

Answer (score 0):

I had the chance to record some great big cat sounds here in SA. The owner of the animals had this amazing way of getting the Lions attention. He would shout out "BIG BOOOYYY!!!" and then the lion would roar. This would happen over and over as it walked towards us. Fantastic. I also recorded an overly friendly leopard who was more interested in purring and licking my hand than growling. But still got some good stuff.